# Analyzing plots in python

Tags: python, plot

I asked this question a couple of weeks ago, but I think I worded it the wrong way for the question to make sense. Basically, I have a plot of pressure versus time, and I'm trying to identify all the intervals where the pressure increases over time. I tried using the derivative function, but that only tells me the slope of the plot at a point, not the interval the changes takes place. Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

The graph is a plot of the pressure data points. Some of the data are NaN, which explains the gaps in the plot.

[image]

From this plot, I would like to be able to write a function that outputs the 65-75 interval as an example of a pressure increase. While I can just derive it from observation, I would like to be able to automate the process, since I have a large data set to go through.

Comment: Are these discrete measurements? Sounds like you want all of the measurement-to-measurement spans (with no intervening measurements) where the pressure increases.

Comment: Can you provide some test data, or things you've tried?

Comment: I'll edit the post to show some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through the list of data points keeping track of the start and end of the current interval and the pressure at both ends. If the next pressure is less than the pressure at the end of the interval, start a new interval. Print out any intervals that contain more than one measurement.

You can decide what to do with gaps: let the interval cross them, or end the current interval?